# Newton Method Simplification

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Hi Everyone I have the following homework assignment problem that I am struggling with:

Consider Newton's method
$$ x_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_k + \frac{a}{x_k} \right), \qquad a > 0, $$
for computing $\alpha = \sqrt{a}$ Let $ d_k = x_{k+1} - x_{k}$

Show that $$ x_{k} = \frac{a}{d_k + \sqrt{d_k^2+a}}$$

Use the above to show $$
  |d_k| = \frac{d_{k-1}^2}{2 \sqrt{d_{k-1}^2 + a}} $$ Discuss the
  significance of this result with regard to the overall behavior of
  Newton's iteration.

I know it's just algebra but I'm having a hard time coming up with that form. I tried getting $x_{k+1}-x_k$ to one side there is always 2$x_{k+1}$ more than $x_k$.

Thank you.

Comment: @Ian, should it not come out $x_{\,k + 1}  + d_{\,k}  = 1/a_{\,k} $ ?

Comment: @GCab You're right. But it goes through similarly with that corrected: $2x_{k+1}=x_k+a/x_k$ hence $x_{k+1}+d_k=a/x_k$ hence $x_k+2d_k=a/x_k$, so $x_k^2+2d_kx_k-a=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand the first part now  @GCab

Comment: @ian can you help me with the second part? I skipped it after I didn't get it figuring I could come back and get it but I can't. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part, about the equation for $d_k$ in terms of $d_{k-1}$? By taking the equation for $x_k$ and subtracting off the equation for $x_{k-1}$, you get $d_{k-1}=$ some combination of $d_{k-1}$ and $d_k$. Can you solve that equation for $d_k$?

Comment: @Ian I will give it a shot. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Ian for the life of me I can't simplify this to work.... Can you walk through the first few steps?

Comment: Perhaps my suggested approach would be algebraically cumbersome (even though in principle it should work). At a glance I'm not immediately seeing a good alternate approach (one that relates $d_k$ to $d_{k-1}$).

Answer (score 1):

You get also
$$
x_k=\sqrt{a+d_k^2}-d_k.
$$
Subtracting the expression for $x_{k-1}$ gives
$$
d_{k-1}=x_k-x_{k-1}=\sqrt{a+d_k^2}-d_k-\sqrt{a+d_{k-1}^2}+d_{k-1}
$$ 
from where you get after squaring
$$
a+d_k^2=d_k^2+2d_k\sqrt{a+d_{k-1}^2}+a+d_{k-1}^2
$$
which reduces to the wanted expression.